# .ttf font converted to webfont has weird space

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I converted this [.ttf](http://www.dafont.com/minecraftia.font) to webfont (used in css) in many online converters but the result always has some weird space at the bottom. It's like a `line-height` and `valign` glitch.

Here is an example how the links looks 
[image: s]

Also [on Ubuntu](http://static.md/e92a65e2496a5f72105bb7b939736015.png) (Linux) and [on other OS it looks different](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/b0545b7e05cedf3f1e0ffa56cbf4cf63809cfedb) (see the top header text "RO EN RU" vertical alignemnt).

Do you have any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: I have no idea how to interpret your example. Can you instead post what it looks like when you use the ttf itself, vs. the converted font? Also, can you say what you are using when you say "webfont"? Another ttf? otf? woff? svg? (if woff: that should be the exact same data as the ttf, just with an additional header that says how it's been compressed. the font's data should be identical, though)

Comment: [Download the font](http://dl.dafont.com/dl/?f=minecraftia), [convert it](http://www.font2web.com/), open `demo.html` in browser and you will see [the underline is too far from the text](http://static.md/790db40d68c286d44dca8317b90c9fb7.png), but when I set `font-family: sans-serif;` to that link with Inspect element, [it looks fine](http://static.md/504a31617d8315d06318d54987fc8ae8.png)

Comment: Setting the font to "sans-serif" changes the font being used. Baseline spacing is dictated *by the font*, so yes, the baseline spacing is going to be different. The only question is: "is it different between the ttf, and the "webfont" you made? If not, then this is simply the baseline as specified by the font you're using.

Comment: [The .ttf and the webfont has the same bottom space](http://static.md/d6fdb7fc9c1d816e885df0258410e1a7.png). But I want to get rid of it.

Comment: It's obvious that the font was wrong designed [`text-decoration: line-through;` looks like `underline`](http://static.md/26952654b1c279b8d1e9fac3c824a1c6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The .ttf](http://static.md/d6fdb7fc9c1d816e885df0258410e1a7.png) and [the webfont](http://static.md/790db40d68c286d44dca8317b90c9fb7.png) has the same bottom space. So there is nothing wrong with the webfont convers. This is just the way the Minecraftia font was designed. The only solution is to find a font editor and to remove the bottom space from every character.

Comment: or, just set a `line-height` and `vertical-align` combination that counteracts the baked in baseline spacing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `line-height` to solve the issue:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33xepaox/)

I used `line-height:0.5` to remove this space in `font-size` of 24

Comment: In your jsfiddle is another font `Minecraft`, the font I am talking about is `Minecraftia`. I use it because it supports more that only latin characters. For e.g. [the Minecraft font does not support russian characters](http://jsfiddle.net/33xepaox/1/).

Comment: would you please give me the link of the font you have made?!

Comment: `line-height` is not the solution, [the glitch is in font](http://static.md/70480142cceb78b1088a6bcfbf3d8736.png). [Here](https://minecraft.space/ru/) you can play with inspect element (but I tried everything...). I converted the `.ttf` to `.svg` and uploaded to https://icomoon.io/app/ and I see that [the characters has blank space at the bottom](http://static.md/7b5411132bd1ab661868cde8904210ab.png). I will try to find an app to edit the font and remove that space. I will keep you up to date.

Comment: I can't find a tool to fix that font (easy). I wrote an email to the font creator, I hope he will reply soon with good news.